# Add Record Rules to leave request Odoo

Tags: odoo, odoo-10, odoo-11

I have used the following rule:

```
[
  '|',
  ('employee_id.user_id',
  '=',
  user.id),
  ('employee_id.parent_id.user_id',
  '=',
  user.id)
]
```

to only allow employees to view their leave applications and have only managers see the subordinates leave applications. However, while applying this rule to everyone (Globally), I would like to still have HR Managers (those given Manager roles i believe its base.group_hr_manager in the module) to be able to see every ones leave request ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't apply this rule to everyone but instead to `base.group_user` which is normal users group anyway. Or better: override/extend the domain of both already existing rules `Employee Holidays *`.
And there already is a rule for "higher" access groups called `Holidays Officer` which provides HR Officer and HR Manager groups all rights for every leave/holiday.